# How to extract the Max value within the same key

Tags: python, dictionary, max

```
{'201001': [36, 88, 65, 113, 51, 88, 37, 106, 96, 68, 104, 93],
 '201002': [65, 85, 97, 52],
 '201003': [85, 63, 86, 52, 71, 53, 51, 48, 52],
 '201004': [82, 39, 97, 114, 74, 30, 97],
 '201005': [97, 66, 109, 98, 94, 78, 99, 53, 67, 56],
 '201006': [116, 98, 39, 69, 33, 84, 62, 39],
 '201007': [72, 98, 37],
 '201008': [98, 31, 99, 105, 109, 72, 30, 34]}
```

I have a dictionary looks something like this, and I want to extract the maximum value within the same key. And create a new dictionary with only one max value per key.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also please don't post images.

Comment: replace the image with writing the data on the Q with code section

Comment: I have tried above method, but still have some issue.

Comment: You get this error because all elements in your lists aren't integers: some of them are strings. Please provide a [mre] that actually reproduces your problem. You will not have this issue if you run your code on the dictionary that you have shown. If you want to force the conversion of the elements of `val` to integer, do that: `{key:max(int(v) for v in val) for key, val in dict_all.items()}`

Comment: See the duplicate for options, using the `max()` function on each list.

Answer (score 2):

```
dict_t = {
    "201001":[1,2,3,4,5],
    "201002":[6,7,8,9,1],
    "201003":[8,9,10,12],
    "201004":[1,20,21,40,100],
}
{key:max(val) for key,val in dict_t.items()}
#output
{'201001': 5, '201002': 9, '201003': 12, '201004': 100}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just tried the code and i encountered some error like this:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
I have check the types of my dictionary elements. which are the same as dict_t you defined.

Comment: @Evelyn: then your lists contain a mixture of strings and integers. Either make sure to clean those up first, or use a generator expression to ignore the strings, or convert those strings to integers first.